# asp.net add multiline and rows to textbox in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, multiline

I'm using VS 2010 and .net 4.  I'm trying to figure out how to make a textbox be multiline and set the rows in codebehind.  Can anyone help.

I'm trying to figure it out for a user control that i'm working on.  So in the properties passed through the to user control it will set the textbox to be a multiline or not.

thanks
shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Textmode Property and The Rows property are what you are looking for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Comment: yep.. but they aren't showing up when i look at the textbox in code behind.. wondered if i was doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

here is how to set up a Texttbox in code behind.

```
      TextBox TranslationTextArea = new TextBox();
      TranslationTextArea.ID = "txtb" + Id;
      TranslationTextArea.Text = text;
      TranslationTextArea.Height = 75;
      TranslationTextArea.Columns = 40;
      TranslationTextArea.MaxLength = 160;
      TranslationTextArea.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
```